# Specifying a set of characters using LIKE

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Apologies for the simple-minded question, but I am new to this.  I am using mySQL Workbench 6.2, and I'm trying to write a simple query that will match any contact name that begins with a J or M from a cust_contact column.  I've seen that one can achieve this by writing

```
SELECT cust_contact
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_contact LIKE '[JM]%'
ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

However, it does not appear that the use of square brackets is supported.  A workaround is

```
SELECT cust_contact
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_contact LIKE 'J%'
    OR cust_contact LIKE 'M%'
ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

but this does not seem like a very elegant solution.  I can't find an explanation of a wildcard similar to [] in the documentation.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, use regular expressions for this:

```
where cust_contact RLIKE '^[JM].*'
```

Answer (score 2):

use Regular expressions ,(either REGEXP or RLIKE).
WHERE cust_contact RLIKE '^[JM].*'
Documentation is : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp